# Activate FaceTime and Messages on Wi-Fi iPad with email address only?

Tags: ipad, messages, apple-id, facetime, ipados

Is it possible to activate FaceTime and Messages on Wi-Fi iPad using Apple ID's email address only?

Someone has Wi-Fi Pad but doesn't have an iPhone. Although there is a phone number associated with the user's Apple ID, that phone number is not associated with FaceTime or Messages because it is not on an iPhone. When trying to activate FaceTime or Messages on the Wi-Fi iPad, the Apple ID email address is shown, but the Sign On option is greyed out and neither Facetime nor Messages can be activated with that email address only.

Answer (score 1):

it is possible. I'll try to walk you through the process in the best and clearest way possible.

1. Create an iCloud account. (You can create this with an existing email address, just click the “use my current email” button)
2. Go to “Settings - Messages - Send and receive” than make sure the email you want to use is checked in both the “receive” and “start” sections. (I know we are setting this up in message settings, it will also apply to FaceTime)
   [image: message settings]
3. Go to “Settings - FaceTime” and check the email in both the “Caller ID” and the “You can be reached at” sections. You may have to scroll down.
   [image]
4. You're done! Open the FaceTime app and begin a call! Note that if you only have the wi-fi model, you will need to be in wi-fi.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can

I am using iPad (6th Generation) with only Wifi and I am able to use the FaceTime & Messages there without an iPhone. My registered number with apple account is being used via an Android phone and not an iPhone.

Comment: Are the messages in Messages Blue or Green?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what shows in Settings, FaceTime, of course after blurring your email and phone number? Was your phone number ever used with an iPhone? Do you remember what were the options when you registered your iPad with FaceTime? In my case only the email address is shown on the iPad and there is no option to sign into FaceTime.

Comment: As your issue is fixed now; do you still want the screenshot @lupincho? 

And no my number is never used with an iPhone. Also, I don't remember the registration options.

@mmmmmm the Messages icon is green in color

Answer (score 0):

It fixed itself after about 4 days. Without changing anything now I see the option to enter the account password and to sign into FaceTime and Messages using the existing email address of the Apple ID. Maybe it was a temporary glitch with the Apple servers or problem with the account.

Answer (score 0):

> [...] the Apple ID email address is shown, **but the Sign On option is greyed out** and neither Facetime nor Messages can be activated with that email address only.

I have experienced this described state too. A grayed out 'Sign in with Apple-ID'. The interface in this state is not very straightforward. I wish we had a picture or better gif of this state.

The 'greyed-out Sign On/In', as you described it, (confusingly) informs us that one cannot sign in, **however, if you click on the e-mail address (and possibly hit enter), it will continue.**

So the GUI / Interface is creating an incorrect expectation of what is going on and what you can do (and can't do).

(I am not 100% sure if it matters, but I would start with iMessage settings page first.)